# Count de Iteraciones

Tags: laravel

tengo el siguiente foreach el cual me devuelve en general 8 valores, sin embargo deseo hacer un count por cada seccion, es decir general deben ser 8, de mi seccion "Registrado" deberia ser 2, de "Proceso" deben ser 2 y 4 para "Aprobados"

Este es mi codigo

```
        {{-- Seccion para registrados --}}
        <tr class="cabecera">
            <td colspan=4>Registrados</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($certificaciones as $info)
            @if($info->asistencia == "Registrado")
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$info->nombre}} {{$info->appaterno}} {{$info->apmaterno}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info->edad}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info->sexo}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info->asistencia}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
        {{-- Seccion para en proceso --}}
        <tr class="cabecera">
            <td colspan=4>En proceso</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($certificaciones as $info)
            @if($info->asistencia == "Proceso")
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$info->nombre}} {{$info->appaterno}} {{$info->apmaterno}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info->edad}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info->sexo}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info->asistencia}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach

        {{-- Seccion para aprobados --}}
        <tr class="cabecera">
            <td colspan=4>Aprobados</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($certificaciones as $info)
            @if($info->asistencia == "Aprobado")
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$info->nombre}} {{$info->appaterno}} {{$info->apmaterno}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info->edad}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info->sexo}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info->asistencia}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
                <tr align="right" class="pie">
                    <th colspan=4>Total: {{count($certificaciones)}}</th>
                </tr>
```

espero haberme explicado bien y poder contar con su ayuda

Comment: ¿No sería mas conveniente hacer el `count` desde la consulta SQL y mandar eso a la vista?

Answer (score 2):

No estoy seguro de que esa sea la mejor forma de enfocar el problema, pero si lo quieres hacer así laravel (en realidad los blade) tienen una variable $loop que te da información del estado de las iteraciones del bucle :

```
@foreach ($certificaciones as $info)
  @if($loop->iteration==8)
     {{-- haz lo que quieras en la itereacion 8 --}}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

No solo está "iteration", tienes "even", "count", etc, la lista completa la puedes ver aqui : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 0):

Otra posibilidad alternativa podría ser:

```php
{{-- Seccion para registrados --}}
@php
    // filtra la colección por el atributo asistencia y guardalo en una variable
    $registrados = $certificaciones->where('asistencia', '=', 'Registrado');
@endphp
<tr class="cabecera">
    <td colspan=4>Registrados</td>
</tr>
{{-- itera sobre la colleción filtrada, ya no necesitas el @if --}}
@foreach ($registrados as $info)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$info->nombre}} {{$info->appaterno}} {{$info->apmaterno}}</td>
        <td>{{$info->edad}}</td>
        <td>{{$info->sexo}}</td>
        <td>{{$info->asistencia}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
<tr align="right" class="pie">
    {{-- aplica count() sobre la colección filtrada --}}
    <th colspan=4>Total Registrados: {{ $registrados->count() }}</th>
</tr>


{{-- lo mismo para las otras --}}
{{-- Seccion para en proceso --}}
@php
    $en_proceso = $certificaciones->where('asistencia', '=', 'Proceso');
@endphp
<tr class="cabecera">
    <td colspan=4>En proceso</td>
</tr>
@foreach ($en_proceso as $info)
    {{-- ... --}}
@endforeach
<tr align="right" class="pie">
    <th colspan=4>Total En Proceso: {{ $en_proceso->count() }}</th>
</tr>

{{-- Seccion para aprobados --}}
{{-- ... --}}

<tr align="right" class="pie">
    <th colspan=4>Total: {{count($certificaciones)}}</th>
</tr>
```